# Same fc6 response for different images

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I follow the instruction in [filter visualization](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/filter_visualization.ipynb) and [classification](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb) example to get the `fc6` (fully connected layer6) response to multiple different images in a folder from a pretrained model (bvlc reference model) but for all of the images I get the same vector.
Here is the code I used:

```
import caffe
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
net = caffe.Classifier(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED,
                   mean=np.load(caffe_root + 'python/caffe/imagenet/ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy').mean(1).mean(1),
                   channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                   raw_scale=255,
                   image_dims=(256, 256))
filenames = next(os.walk(path))[2]
fc6Respose=[]
for i in range(0,len(filenames)): 
    input_image = caffe.io.load_image(path+filenames[i])
    scores = net.predict([input_image])
    feat = net.blobs['fc6'].data[4]
    fc6Respose.append(feat)
```

PS: Is there any simple way to store this data in a file (like txt or csv) that can be used for later and can be read and opened without using Python?

Comment: The link to the tutorial you used is broken. Can you fix it please?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing only a *single* element of the `fc6` response (the fourth one). It might be the case that this element in the output is degenerate for the kind of inputs you tested it on. Try looking at the entire `fc6` response.

Moreover, I'm not sure what model you are using, but are you certain this specific model expects its `mean` argument to be per-channel mean and not per-pixel?

BTW, you are using `oversample` for your input (the default option in [`caffe.Classifier.predict`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/classifier.py#L47)) this means the output you are getting is actually an *average* of 10 responses to slightly different input image (different cropping+mirroring). You might want to disable this option using

```
scores = net.predict([input_image], oversample=False)
```

Comment: I used all the elements and still get the same response.
The mean argument is exactly what I copied from the example.

Comment: @Proud what caffe model are you using? where did you download it from? what are the wieghts you are using? Have you tried the same code with a different model/weights? does the features' values stay the same from image to image? and from model to model?